# Find a block that contains "tag" using regex

Tags: python, regex, github, github-pages

I write a python script that uses `re` to change Markdown files so as to make them readable in Github Pages. I have trouble finding a block that contains "tag"(s).

An unaligned math block is something like below (see the last example for an aligned math block)

```
$$
a+b=10\\
c+d=20
$$
```

where there is an empty line before and after the block to make math blocks more distinguishable. I can find such blocks using regex with `(^\n\$\$\n(?!\\begin\{align\})(((.*?)\n)*?(.)*)\$\$\n\n)`. A unaligned math block with "tag"(s) is

```
$$
a+b=10 \tag 1\\
c+d=20\\
e+f=30 \tag {10}
$$
```

I want to find these blocks with one or more "tag"s so that I can make them aligned:

```
$$
\begin{align}
a+b=10 \tag 1\\
c+d=20\\
e+f=30 \tag {10}
\end{align}
$$
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: As a suggestion, [edit] your question and include a tag to the language you are using for better visibility.

Comment: @DapperDuck Thank you. I've updated tags to include `github-pages`? Is there anything unclear in my question?

Comment: I meant the regex language, because different programming languages have different regex rules.

Comment: @DapperDuck Thank you. I see. I use python and have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a quick walkaround, which encompasses any math blocks with `\begin{align}...\end{align}`:

```py
# content contains all text
content = re.sub(r'(^\n\$\$\n)(?!\\begin\{align\})(((.*?)\n)*?(.)*)(\$\$\n\n)', r'\1\\begin{align}\n\2\\end{align}\n\6', content, flags=re.M)
```